# A cross-origin error was thrown. react doesn't have access to the actual error object in development in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, next.js

i am trying to clone data from props to state inside constructor.

```
this.state = {
  showAttemptModal: false,
  showProgressbar: true,
  data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.data))
}
```

But getting cross-origin error. Why this is happening.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] and a *complete* error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup your server to support CORS and still getting this error, most likely it is an issue with reactjs while processing response from the server. In my case it was happening while trying to parse invalid response into JSON.

Answer (score -1):

CORS error has nothing to do with cloning data from props to state.
You need to pass following property for same in your request header while fetching data from API :

> `{Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*",
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"}`

Comment: No! Those are response headers and have no place being in the request. (And we don't know what kind of cross-origin error the OP is having).